# How to refresh the value of a property in Ember automatically

Tags: ember.js

First off I think that the subject question may not contain the correct context in what I am looking for, but I will try to explain myself.

I am fairly new to Ember, and I am looking for a way to take a property and refresh the value of it, periodically instead of based on the view refreshing, action, or a template element causing the property to change.

This is kind of a generic example, but it closely relates to what I am doing:

- I have a utility that calculates the size of objects or in specific to what I am doing it will calculate the size of the localStorage.
- I store the value of that calculation in a property and use it in a "service" and other places throughout the app.

  - Everyplace where I use this property is just a static view, and the user will have no interaction in doing something that will cause an action to update that property.

  any suggestions?

Comment: What causes the property to change? Also, what version of Ember are you on? If Octane, using a `@tracked` property in the service means anywhere it’s used in a template will automatically update if the value changes.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the ways that Ember Octane is just javascript. You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#setInterval) and calculate the value at whatever interval you like then set it to a [@tracked](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/tracked-properties/) property on the service. Whenever your interval function updates the property it will be changed anywhere you've displayed it.

Comment: to add to this answer, `@tracked` is pretty new. If you're still on pre-Octane ember, it's simply enough to set the value on a `service` via `this.set`. Anywhere you reference `someService.foo` in templates will automatically update when you call `someService.set('foo', ...`